# Prevent Firefox's "Well this is embarrassing" screen from appearing at first login only

Tags: windows-7, firefox, batch-file

My parents have Windows 7, Firefox 30 and two user accounts which they regularly flip between and then shutdown the computer.

As a result the "well this is embarrassing" page appears frequently when they first log onto the computer. Since I'm not going to be able to easily train them to exit Firefox cleanly on both accounts before shutting down (and, let's be honest, I shouldn't really have to) I wondered if there was an alternative solution.

My initial thought was that, rather than disable a useful piece of functionality, it might be better to run something at login that deletes or modifies whatever file it is that causes this page to appear. In other words, upon first login they'll never see this page, but subsequent crashes will get the session restore screen when they restart the browser (unless, of course, they reboot the computer).

Some google searches suggests that deleting `sessionstore.*` from within the profile folder (located at `%appdata%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\<random ID>\`) would do the trick. However some other pages caution against doing this.

What would be the right way to achieve this?

(Footnote: I've already tried a re-install and a fresh install without extensions, this is about hacking Firefox to work the way my parents use their computer and will continue to use their computer, whatever I tell them)

Comment: Why not just tell them to ignore that page?  Is there a case when you do want them to consider that page and give you a call?

Comment: I've told them exactly that for the time being, but it would be nice to go the extra mile and stop the damn thing from appearing the first time they log in :)

Comment: I use the TabMixPlus add-on, and I've never had that message. If I fail to shut down, whether because of a crash or forgetfulness, I am always prompted if I want to restore the crashed session or another from the saved list. No embarrassment.